# docker wordpress custom theme

Tags: wordpress, laravel, docker

I'm very new on Docker.
I'm trying to create a docker container: wordpress - mysql image. I can make it run as shown in tutorial (with a docker-compose.yml) that fetches the latest versions of the packages.

But now I want to customize my wordpress code. Where should I do that? What's the flow to make docker-containers for wordpress (or Laravel projects)?

Answer (score 0):

To start, you can mount a local version of the `wp-content` directory to your container. This will make that content persist instead of being destroyed whenever your container is ever removed.

If you're using a `docker-compose.yml` file, this is as simple as adding a line like this:

```
 volumes:
   - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

Then, if you want to beef things up a bit, you could use Composer to define any plugin dependencies, and run `composer install` to install them.

You can see an example of this setup here:

https://github.com/alexmacarthur/wp-skateboard